# How to change Google Accounts using library(googlesheets)?

Tags: r, r-googlesheets

I experience some problems. I use a R-Script on one machine successfully. The same script used on a different computer causes problems:

```
# Here I register the sheet
```

`browser <- gs_title("Funnel Daily")`

`browser<-gs_edit_cells(ws="Classic Browser", browser, input = ClassicBrowser, anchor = "A1",byrow = FALSE,
                    col_names = NULL, trim = F,verbose = TRUE)`

```
Auto-refreshing stale OAuth token.
Error in gs_lookup(., "sheet_title", verbose) : 
 "Funnel Daily" doesn't match sheet_title of any sheet returned by gs_ls() (which        should reflect user's Google Sheets home screen).
   > browser <- gs_title("Funnel Daily")
Error in gs_lookup(., "sheet_title", verbose) : 
  "Funnel Daily" doesn't match sheet_title of any sheet returned by gs_ls() (which   should reflect user's Google Sheets home screen).`
```

if using `gl_ls()` I get a message about an google account which I also frequently use. So is there a way maybe via a token or so to differentiate between accounts or how can I solve that `issue`. I mean how can I force `googlesheets` to access some specific account?
Currently I'm using the `token`of the account which corresponds to `Funnel Daily`. The only possibility I can think of which may have caused the issue is that the browser-authentification was done with the account which not included `Funnel Daily`..I just confused them. 
I tried to remove `googlesheets` as well as `httr`with all dependencies. But when running the `library(googlesheets)` and asking `gs_user` googlesheets always refers to the account which doesnt include the specific sheet.

Comment: `gs_auth` returns a "token". each token can be saved to an R data file and then passed _to_ calls to `gs_auth` to change the the internally saved token  for the current session. you probably cached credentials after some use of `googlesheets` and the cache file should be `.httr-oauth` in your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

Include your credentials and confirm the `browser authentication` via your Funnel Daily Google Account:

```
 options(googlesheets.client_id = "",
    googlesheets.client_secret = "",
    googlesheets.httr_oauth_cache = FALSE)

gs_auth(token = NULL, new_user = FALSE,
    key = getOption("googlesheets.client_id"),
    secret = getOption("googlesheets.client_secret"),
    cache = getOption("googlesheets.httr_oauth_cache"), verbose = TRUE)
```

Cheers